# Shape layer height = composition height in ExtendScript

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I have a plugin that detects whether the pixel width or height of an object is greater.
It works great for other objects, but with shape layers, it just says the composition size.
My code is

```
 pixelWidth = +currentLayer.width * +width / 100;
 pixelHeight = +currentLayer.height * +height / 100;
```

Variables width and height are the scale property, and I make it apply the percentage of Scale property affect the outcome, so its the appearing scale.

Thanks

Comment: Downvote because this is not a real question.

Comment: Why isn't it a question? Sure syntactically it might be a bit off, but it's a programming problem that needed a solution isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I guess your question is "How to get the width and height of a shape layer in After Effects?". Am I right? Why don't you say so. As you found out the width and height properties only return the width and height of the comp. For text and shape layers you need to use the `sourceRectAtTime(timeT, extents)` method. It will return an object like this `{top, left, width, height}` these are measured from the layers anchor.

```
var layer = app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers[0];
$.writeln(layer.width); // gives the comp width
$.writeln(layer.height);// gives the comp height

// from the After Effects Scripting Guide

// AVLayer sourceRectAtTime() method
// app.project.item(index).layer(index).sourceRectAtTime(timeT, extents) Description
// Retrieves the rectangle bounds of the layer at the specified time index,
// corrected for text or shape layer content.
// Use, for example, to write text that is properly aligned to the baseline.

/**
 * sourceRectAtTime
 * @param {Number} The time index, in seconds. A floating-point value.
 * @param {Boolean} True to include the extents, false otherwise. Extents apply to shape layers, increasing the size of the layer bounds as necessary.
 * 
 * @return {Object} A JavaScript object with four attributes, {top, left, width, height}.
 */
var bounds = layer.sourceRectAtTime(0, true);
$.writeln(bounds.toSource());
```